# How can I export a GeoJSON file from R?

Tags: r, geojson, export

The write. function allows one to export a JSON file, but it does not seem to work for a GeoJSON file.

This is the code i ran:

```
write(map,"Map Layer2.GeoJSON")
```

and this was the error produced:

```
Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
  argument 1 (type 'S4') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`write` is just a wrapper for `cat` (package `base`). See `?write`:

> Write Data to a File
>
> **Description**
>
> The data (usually a matrix) x are written to file file. If x is a
>   two-dimensional matrix you need to transpose it to get the columns in
>   file the same as those in the internal representation.

To write a GeoJSON file, you can use `writeOGR()` instead (package `rgdal`):

```
library("rgdal")
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) = c("x", "y")
class(meuse)
# [1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
writeOGR(meuse, "test_geojson", layer="meuse", driver="GeoJSON")
```

Comment: I'm seeing that `layer` is required, but isn't used (`dsn` is used to name the output file). Any idea why?

Answer (score 8):

2021 Solution with the `sf` package

```
library(sf)
library(rgdal)
data(meuse)
meuse_sf = st_as_sf(meuse, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 28992, agr = "constant")
st_write(meuse_sf, "meuse.geojson")
```

Answer (score 7):

Just to clarify rcs great answer and Matt's question for beginners. The dsn should be the path and full file name, layer is required but ignored. No, not sure why.

```
library("rgdal")
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) = c("x", "y")
writeOGR(meuse, dsn="path/test_geojson.GeoJSON", layer="meuse", driver="GeoJSON")
```