# In R, How to read in GeoJSON file, modify, then export back as new GeoJSON file

Tags: r, geojson

Familiar with R, but not GIS.

I have a GeoJSON file with tens of polygons, each of which has thousands of coordinates, and I want to read it into R, perform some validation of the structure, fix where needed, and export it back to file.

I've used `FROM_GeoJson` (package `geojsonR`) to read in the file. It represents it as a list of lists. I can easily manipulate this structure, but there isn't, for example, a corresponding `TO_GeoJson`. What is the easiest way to export this to file?

I read this question: [How can I export a GeoJSON file from R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147219/how-can-i-export-a-geojson-file-from-r), and it shows how to generate a GeoJSON from a data frame. But I would have to convert my list of lists to a data frame. I'm unclear how to specify the coordinates when there is more than one point, however.

I'm hoping for a straightforward way that even a novice GIS/R person would easily know so I don't have to spend several hours learning how to do it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution that might make knowledgeable GeoJSON and GIS people balk. But I switched to a pure JSON library and just treated everything as strings. This works for my purposes.

The library `rjson` provides the `toJSON` function which converts the R object into a corresponding JSON string, which I can just write to file.

Answer (score 5):

If its a GeoJSON file and you have the `sf` package and your `sf` package has been linked with a version of `GDAL` with a `geoJSON` driver (all pretty common stuff so unless you are on an exotic platform...) then the standard `sf` reading and writing functions work.

Example using some `geoJSON` points from the `spData` package:

```
> gj = system.file("shapes/cycle_hire.geojson",package="spData")
```

`gj` is a path in the file system. Now read it to an `sf` spatial data frame:

```
> gjsf = st_read(gj)
Reading layer `cycle_hire' from data source `/opt/R-3.6.1/library/spData/shapes/cycle_hire.geojson' using driver `GeoJSON'
Simple feature collection with 742 features and 5 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -0.2367699 ymin: 51.45475 xmax: -0.002275 ymax: 51.54214
CRS:            4326
```

And write. The output driver is inferred from the file name:

```
> st_write(gjsf, "/tmp/output.geojson")
Writing layer `output' to data source `/tmp/output.geojson' using driver `GeoJSON'
Writing 742 features with 5 fields and geometry type Point.
```

How you "manipulate/validate" the `gjsf` structure is your next job - its a spatial data frame which means it has a "geometry" column with the location info, and attribute columns with the information for each location, be it points, lines or polygons.

Comment: Thanks. Is there required to be a field called "dsn" in the file? I followed your instructions (without changing the file yet) and the error I see is this: "Error: `dsn` must point to a source, not an empty string." My file doesn't have such a field.

Comment: If you are trying to read the geojson file from the spData package like I did you need to install the spData package. What is `gj` evaluating to? An empty string? That would seem to be the error - you are trying to do `st_read("")`

Comment: Even though I have a workable solution that I posted below, I tried this for interest's sake. Didn't realize `spData` was another package I had to install. But even after installing, I still get `gj` evaluating to "".

Comment: Ok that's odd. Try it on your GeoJSON file - set `gj="/path/to/my.geoJSON"` and then `st_read(gj)` and see what you get. It should be a spatial data frame which comes from the `sf` package and is the usual format for spatial data in R these days.